# R: Representar función a trozos

Tags: r

Estoy intentando representar la siguiente función de densidad con R:

```
$$
f(x)= 
\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{lcc}
       0 &   si  & x < 0 \\
    \\ 2-2\cdot x &  si & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
    \\ 0 &  si  & x > 1
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que tiene el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código en R:

```
x = seq(0, 1, length = 1000) #Secuencia de 1.000 puntos entre 0 y 1

plot(
      x, 2-2*x, #f(x) entre 0 y 1
      type = "l", #Representación de tipo línea
      main = "Función de densidad",
      ylab = "f(x)",
      xlab = "x",
      lwd = 1, #Grosor
      xlim = c(-0.5, 1.5), #Ampliación de los ejes
      ylim = c(-0.5, 2.5)
    )

lines(c(-1, 0), c(0 ,0), lwd = 1) #f(x) para valores menores de 0
lines(c(1, 0), c(2, 0), lwd = 1) #f(x) para valores mayores de 1

points(0, 0, pch = 1) #Puntos de transición
points(0, 2, pch = 19)
points(1, 0, pch = 19)

text(0, 0, labels = "(0, 0)", pos = 1)
text(0, 2, labels = "(0, 2)", pos = 3)
text(1, 0, labels = "(1, 0)", pos = 1)
```

Sin embargo, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir:

```
lines(c(1, 0), c(2, 0), lwd = 1) #f(x) para valores mayores de 1
```

Representa una recta entre (0, 0) y (1, 2) en vez de entre (1, 0) y (2, 0).

¿Por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `lines` espera un vector para los valores de `x` y otro para el de `y` y lo que entiendo que estas intentando es pasar directamente los puntos A y B, deberías modificar esto:

```
lines(c(1, 0), c(2, 0), lwd = 1)
```

por

```
lines(c(1, 2), c(0, 0), lwd = 1)
```

El primer vector, son los valores de `x` que va del 1 al 2 y el siguiente es el de `y` que siempre es 0.

Comment: Vale, estaba dando por hecho que `lines` funcionaba tal que: `lines(c(x1, y1), c(x2, y2))`. Muchas gracias, Patricio.